# form position is changing when loader coming on top of the form

Tags: html, css

The problem is when submitting the form a loader comes on the top of form but when the loader comes the position of whole form is coming down.
The form position is coming down when loaders comes.
Is there any css solutions to make it work?

```
<form id="login_form">
    <div class="loader-container" id="loader-container" style="display:none;">
        <img alt="loader" src="ring.gif" /> <span>Loading Please Wait..</span>
    </div>

    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="mail" id="email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pasword" id="paswrd" />
    <button class="submit" onclick="login();" id='submit'>Sign In</button>
    </div>
</form>

<style>
#email,
#paswrd {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadfe3 !important;
    border-top: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    border-right: 0px !important;
    border-left: 0px !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

 .submit {
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 11px 15%;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15% !important;
    background-color: #d71921;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#login_form {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1%;
    width: 70%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

when styling your page it would be better if you stacked your elements using css z-index property. -1 makes the form element appear beneath the loader

```
#login_form {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

or 
make the loader element the top most element

```
 #loader {
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through it, it will show loader in center of form with moving it down.

```css
#email,
#paswrd {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadfe3 !important;
    border-top: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    border-right: 0px !important;
    border-left: 0px !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

 .submit {
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 11px 15%;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15% !important;
    background-color: #d71921;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#login_form {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1%;
    width: 70%;position:relative;
}
div#loader-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);text-align:center;
}
div#loader-container span {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form id="login_form">
    <div class="loader-container" id="loader-container" style="display:none;">
        <img alt="loader" src="ring.gif" /> <span>Loading Please Wait..</span>
    </div>

    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="mail" id="email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pasword" id="paswrd" />
    <button class="submit" onclick="login();" id='submit'>Sign In</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: the loader will come on the top of input fields i dont want z-index things .

Comment: can you send the image, what exactly you want?

Comment: [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/sahithi2/Lykzg12t/13/)                                                                         can you check this fiddle when the loader comes the login form is coming down . when loader goes it will adjust to previous position.

Comment: div#loader-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
form#login_form {
    position: relative;
}

Comment: just add this css